# How to join (without concatenating) two result sets of two fields together as one long ‘list’

Tags: sql, concatenation

What SQL Code do I require to perform the following? :

I have one table (lets arbitrarily call the table 'Names'):

```
ID | Name1  | Name2
---+--------+-------
1  | Fred   | Jack
2  | Jack   | Jim
3  | Jill   | Fred
4  | Jim    | Jack
```

etc

What I'd like is to produce is a single list of Name1 and Name2 (I don't even care about Grouping or Ordering) as such, but I would like to keep the original 'ID' association with the name:

```
ID | Names
---+------
1  | Fred
1  | Jack
2  | Jill
2  | Jim
3  | Jack
3  | Jim
4  | Fred
4  | Jack
```

Why do I want to do this?  Because it looks easy and as a SQL coder I should probably be able to perform this task, but I can't figure out a solution that will create this output.  Further more I've only manage to find people with the desire to concatenate the fields, which is a simple task, but I'm not interested in concatenation.

Additional Question: Would the SQL query be vastly different if Name1 field was in a different table to Name2? (if it is different, what would it look like?)

Additional Question: Would the SQL query be simpler if we didn't care about the ID field?  If so, what would that look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this form to include the id, and give you a specific ordering by ID.

```
SELECT n.id, n.name1 FROM names n
UNION
SELECT m.id, m.name2 from names m
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

If it were in a different table, the use of UNION doesn't have to change, since we're bringing the results from the table together, and ordering them by ID.  This doesn't mean that the data is related, though.

```
SELECT n.id, n.name FROM name_one n
UNION
SELECT m.id, m.name from name_two m
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

If we didn't care about the ID field, it would be ever so lightly simpler - it's just selecting one column at that point.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT ID, Name1 as Names FROM person
UNION
SELECT ID, Name2 as Names FROM person
```

?

. . What you mean by "without concatenating"?

Comment: Where the word 'concatenate' means to join two strings together; for instance 'A + B' = 'AB'.  I don't want to do this.

Comment: I think the `UNION` will do, then. But you are actually doing two separated queries and then joining them. If you want duplicates, use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: UNION doesn't work, as it only keeps related records. In the past I have tried UNION ALL.  But I need to figure out how to keep the ID.  Cheers.

Comment: Ok, I got it now.
SELECT ID, Name1 as Names FROM person
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name2 as Names FROM person

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Please vote my answer up and accept it if it solved your problem so it is easier for other people to find it when searching in the future.

Comment: @DiegoNunes, I had voted your answer up, but that was before I saw you begging for votes.

Comment: @DanBracuk It's not about "begging for votes", it's just that people forget to accept the answers when they are correct and it lies forever as _unanswered_ when they are actually already solved.